# Javascript searching an array object // How do i get to console log only trails that are at least 4.0 miles in the code

Tags: javascript

Trying to use the filter method to find the trails that are at least 4 miles in the hikingBermudaObject. Is there a better way i can do this?

```js
          const hikingBermuda = {
            author: "Cecile Davidson",
            price: 17.95,
            title: "Hiking Bermuda",
            sections: {
              0: {
                sectionName: "Preface",
                chapters: [
                  {
                    name: "Trail Locator",
                    page: 12,
                  },
                ],
              },
              1: {
                sectionName: "Introduction",
                chapters: [
                  {
                    name: "Map Legend",
                    page: 24,
                  },
                  {
                    name: "Rating System",
                    page: 22,
                  },
                ],
              },
              2: {
                sectionName: "West End",
                chapters: [
                  {
                    name: "Botanical Gardens",
                    page: 63,
                  },
                  {
                    name: "Rockaway, Whale Bay Park",
                    page: 45,
                  },
                  {
                    name: "Somerset Bridge, Hog Bay Park",
                    page: 39,
                  },
                ],
              },
            },
            trails: [
              {
                name: "Somerset to Hamilton Railway Trail",
                page: 75,
                section: "West End",
                distanceInMiles: 11.7,
                rating: "Hardy",
              },
              {
                name: "City of Hamilton",
                page: 69,
                section: "West End",
                distanceInMiles: 2.4,
                rating: "Easy",
              },
              {
                name: "St. George's Point",
                page: 131,
                section: "East End",
                distanceInMiles: 3.6,
                rating: "Moderate",
              },
              {
                name: "South Shore Beaches",
                page: 53,
                section: "West End",
                distanceInMiles: 5.0,
                rating: "Moderate",
              },`enter code here`
            ],`enter code here`
          };
```

Comment: You can use a simple method called <Array>.filter, don't need to create a seperate question for this :)

Comment: The method is on [`Array.prototype.filter`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Answer (score -1):

### Description

There are some errors in the above JSON.

The below is an example of how this would be a good use case for JavaScript's [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function.

### Example

```js
const hikingBermuda = {
  author: 'Cecile Davidson',
  price: 17.95,
  title: 'Hiking Bermuda',
  sections: {
    0: {
      sectionName: 'Preface',
      chapters: [{
        name: 'Trail Locator',
        page: 12
      }]
    },
    1: {
      sectionName: 'Introduction',
      chapters: [{
        name: 'Map Legend',
        page: 24
      },
      {
        name: 'Rating System',
        page: 22
      }
      ]
    },
    2: {
      sectionName: 'West End',
      chapters: [{
        name: 'Botanical Gardens',
        page: 63
      },
      {
        name: 'Rockaway, Whale Bay Park',
        page: 45
      },
      {
        name: 'Somerset Bridge, Hog Bay Park',
        page: 39
      }
      ]
    }
  },
  trails: [{
    name: 'Somerset to Hamilton Railway Trail',
    page: 75,
    section: 'West End',
    distanceInMiles: 11.7,
    rating: 'Hardy'
  },
  {
    name: 'City of Hamilton',
    page: 69,
    section: 'West End',
    distanceInMiles: 2.4,
    rating: 'Easy'
  },
  {
    name: "St. George's Point",
    page: 131,
    section: 'East End',
    distanceInMiles: 3.6,
    rating: 'Moderate'
  },
  {
    name: 'South Shore Beaches',
    page: 53,
    section: 'West End',
    distanceInMiles: 5.0,
    rating: 'Moderate'
  }
  ]
}

const mileLimit = 4
const trails = hikingBermuda.trails.filter((el) => {
  return el.distanceInMiles <= mileLimit
})

console.log(trails)
```